# How could i make my text smoother?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size, smoothing

So i want my text to be more smoother, because right now its a bit pixelated.
Here is a picture of my page:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/POx2dzFpSii54oAcOJVLgg.png
Here is a picture of another page which uses the same font but its not pixelated:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/ywhJmpfDSLePNatLorUfTQ.png

**EDIT:**

Here is some html and css code for the navbar and header

```
<body>
<!--HEADER-->
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <i class="fa fa-star faiconfix" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left"></i>
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/logo.png" alt="Hiraeth logo">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!--END HEADER-->
<!--NAVBAR-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home faiconfix" aria-hidden="true"></i>Homepage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="ex1"><i class="fa fa-diamond faiconfix" aria-hidden="true"></i>Store *30% OFF*</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments faiconfix" aria-hidden="true"></i>Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart faiconfix" aria-hidden="true"></i>Vote</a></li>
                        <li class="navfixborder"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-send faiconfix" aria-hidden="true"></i>Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--END NAVBAR-->
```

CSS:

```
 html {
        font-family: Roboto, 'Open Sans', Arial;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: .9em;
        width:100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: Roboto, 'Open Sans', Arial;
      }

  .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-left: 2px solid #333240;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to see why it is a bit pixelated?

Comment: i have no idea why is it pixelated, i could add the whole bootstrap css and html but that would take up too much space, i have no idea which part of the code i should add **EDIT:** i added the html code

Comment: you can try to reproduce the issue in small piece of code, e.g. showing only the 'homepage' field, with the classes which it is using

Comment: Ok, i added some html and css